# How can I pull only the key names from Windows Server AppFabric?

Tags: appfabric

Is there a method to pull all of the cache keys from the Windows Server version of AppFabric without the object?

I know that I can use code like this:

```
foreach(string regionName in cache.GetSystemRegions())
{
   foreach (var cacheItem in cache.GetObjectsInRegion(regionName))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Key={0} -- Value ={1}", cacheItem.Key,cacheItem.Value);
   }
}
```

I want to avoid pulling the caheItem.Value part back over the network.

From what I can tell by looking at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SimpleClient, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.RoutingClient, and Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory; this does not appear to be possible.

DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String) calls DataCacheFactory.Create, which is hard coded to return either SimpleClient or RoutingClient. I can't plug in that way to give myself a different implementation of DataCache without using reflection.

The implementations of SendMsgAndWait in SimpleClient and RoutingClient force the de-serialization of the byte[][] Value DataMember of the ResponseBody into object ValueObj with a call like Utility.Deserialize(partialResponse.Value, false);

If the developers had deferred the deserialization until when ValueObj {get;} was called, this would be a non issue for the tax.

This would not address the issue of the network traffic. It would still require sending the serialized object with the AppFabric message.

I do not see another way around avoiding the deserialization overhead without a custom DataCache implementation and forcing the use of it via reflection. I do not see any way to eliminate the network bandwidth of moving the serialized objects only to find their keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is this, Jeremy, the current implementation does NOT support the feature of "pulling all keys". Any workaround on the client-side won't help as the server-side does not support it at all. I'm sorry this is probably not the answer you wanted. From the horse's mouth, though. :) //J